# remove pattern with random numbers (digits) from php files

Tags: grep, find, sed, xargs

I am trying to remove or replace the digits ((random numbers)) in big numbers of php files using find & xargs and grep with sed etc .. the numbers looks like that
inside the php file

```
 /web/20150618155933/http//www.example.com/
 src='/web/30110218335932im_/img/example.png'
( /web/20150703082231js_/https://me-ssl : /web/20150703082231/http://me-cdn')
```

the good things the numbers is static on 14 digits only ..
but end with either js_ im_ or only numbers,,
so i was use the below command

```
find . -type f -name '*.php*' -print0 | xargs egrep -hEo '/web/\<[[:digit:]]{14}\>/' | xargs sed -i 0 ?????
```

i stuck in two things 
1. integrated with sed command 
2. add in search Pattern end with either js_ im_ or only digits numbers

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you:

```
find . -type f -name \*.php -exec sed -i 's:/web/[0-9]\+:/web/:g' {} \;
```

?

Comment: nop , I've run it doesn't do anything

Comment: It does work as expected. Please do not downvote without before attempting troubleshooting. Your system details might help helping you.

Answer (score 0):

in the end found this work with me

```
find . -type f -name '*.php*' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/\/web\/\([0-9,a-z,_]*\)[\/]//g'
```

thanks guys

Comment: (1) Yes, `\/` works, but, when you are doing a search and replace that includes slashes, it’s often clearer to use some other character as the delimiter.  I like vertical bar (`|`); other people prefer `!`, `@`, `#`, or anything else that doesn’t otherwise appear in the command and isn’t a special character.  (2) `[…]` counts as a single regular expression; therefore, so does `[…]*`.  So you don’t need to enclose it in `\(…\)` (unless you’re inserting it as part of the replacement string).  (3) Don’t include `,` in a `[…]` expression unless you want it to match a comma.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) I know your examples don’t show any capital letters, but, do you have capital letters in your data?  If you do, you need to include `A-Z` in your regex.  (5) Why did you put the last `\/` into brackets?   Just for clarity?  (6) Your `sed` command can be compressed to `'s|/web/[0-9a-z_]*/||g'` (or, if applicable, `…[0-9A-Za-z_]*…`).